# What was the number of the block in which SegWit got activated? And first transaction?

Tags: segregated-witness, segwit2x

It was definitely on August 24th 2017, but not sure about the block number. Many sources reference block 481,822; but others state 481,824.

Also, even if this was the first block to allow segwit transactions, what was the first very block that contained one of them?

Comment: I believe the first transaction is in block 481825, because this is the block where my parser fails.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old question but probably someone else needs to know the same:

SegWit was activated in block 481824 and that block has two p2wpkh txs:

```
dfcec48bb8491856c353306ab5febeb7e99e4d783eedf3de98f3ee0812b92bad in block 0000000000000000001c8018d9cb3b742ef25114f27563e3fc4a1902167f9893
f91d0a8a78462bc59398f2c5d7a84fcff491c26ba54c4833478b202796c8aafd in block 0000000000000000001c8018d9cb3b742ef25114f27563e3fc4a1902167f9893
```

I have to run my script against testnet in order to find the best p2wpk tx.

Comment: So, block 481824 is the first block that *could* contain a SwgWit transaction according to consensus or is it just the first block that actually does?

Comment: it is the first block that actually does. There is no mention of any specify block height in the segwit activation mechanism, there is a start time and a timeout time (a time frame) when it was possible to activate it. Take a look at the code https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L101

Comment: I will try and find out exactly.

Comment: According to [this Question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60095/segwit-is-activated-due-to-bip91) it was indeed block 481824.

Comment: @lontivero just for others "now" is line https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/chainparams.cpp#L76

Comment: thanks for that link!

Answer (score 0):

Blockchair indexes this BTW: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?s=block_id(asc)&q=has_witness(true)#f=hash,block_id,input_count,output_count,time,output_total,output_total_usd,fee_usd,has_witness which confirms the 481,824. I filtered by "has witness" and sorted by block.